# Ef many to many linq query that gets objects that have all list members

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

I am using entity framework. I have two domain models.

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}   

public class Feature
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

Animal and feature have many to many relationship so I have these tables in DB:

- Animal
- Feature
- AnimalFeature

I get a list

```
var featureList = new List<Feature> { new Feature { Name = "f1" }, new Feature { Name = "f2" } };
```

How do i get a list of animals which contains **all features** in *featureList*

Any help will be appreciated. I'm stuck on this one really bad.

Comment: did you include the navigation property in your linq query?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro no I have not. But I don't see how it will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var features =  { "f1","f2" };
var query = from a in dc.Animals
            where ( from f in a.Features
                    where features.Contains(f.Name)
                    select f).Count() == features.Length
            select a;
```

I suggest you use a primitive type collection instead a List of `Features` because EF only works with primitive types and enum types when you need to check if several elements are contained in a specific set. You can't compare two custom objects in your `where` condition. Remember this query is going to be translated to sql, and EF doesn't know how to translate the comparison between two objects. So, as I said before, you should use primitive types or enum types in this kind of query. You can select the names or Ids of the features you need to have the animals and compare with that collection as I did above.

Anyway, I think you can also do this another query using the `Any` extension method:

```
var featureList = new List<Feature> { new Feature { Name = "f1" }, new Feature { Name = "f2" } };

var query = from a in dc.Animals
            where ( from f in a.Features
                    where featureList.Any(e=>e.Name==f.Name)
                    select f).Count() == featureList.Count
            select a;
```

But I particularly prefer the first variant.